# tvOS/Swift 3: How fix broken UICollectionView selection animation?

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, tvos

I have subclassed UICollectionViewCell so that a parallax effect can be applied to the whole cell rather than just the image in the cell. The parallax effect works as I want it to, but it breaks the push button like animation that happens when the remote button is pressed on a selected cell.

collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) is called as it should be the the remote button, there's just not any animation.

I presume I have to do the animation, but don't know how to trigger it, or, indeed, how to do it.

This is my UICollectionViewCell:

```
class CollectionViewCellA: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bkgImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var title: UILabel!

override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    struct wrapper {
        static let s_atvMotionEffect = UIAppleTVMotionEffectGroup()
    }

    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations( {
        var scale : CGFloat = 0.0
        if self.isFocused {
            self.addMotionEffect(wrapper.s_atvMotionEffect)
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75;
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 32.0;
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 16);
            scale = 1.2
        } else {
            self.removeMotionEffect(wrapper.s_atvMotionEffect)
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0);
            scale = 1.0
        }
        let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
        self.layer.setAffineTransform(transform)
    },completion: nil)

   }
}
```

This the UIViewController where the UICollectionView resides:

```
class HomeVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {


    @IBOutlet var freeContentCV: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var collectionViewB: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet var mainImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        freeContentCV.delegate = self
        collectionViewB.delegate = self

        freeContentCV.dataSource = self
        collectionViewB.dataSource = self
    }


    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        self.scrollView!.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1920, height: 2500)
    }

    override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        //print(UIScreen.main.focusedView)
    }

    // Collection View Methods

    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        if collectionView == self.freeContentCV{
        return 10
       }

     return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if collectionView == self.freeContentCV {
        let cellA = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellA", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellA
        cellA.bkgImage.image = UIImage(named: "vincent")
        cellA.title.text = "TITLE"
        return cellA
        }

        let cellB = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CellB", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellA
        cellB.image.image = UIImage(named: "vincent")
        cellB.title.text = "TITLE"
        return cellB
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

       // What goes here to trigger an animation, if anything? 
    }

}
```

I presume the didSelectItemAt function is where I have to trigger the push-button animation, but I don't know how to access the UICollectionViewCell to animate it, or even if that's possible with the arrangement I have. At the edge of my iOS/tvOS understanding here, so I am not sure of the right question(s) to ask.

I've looked at many sources and have  not yet found any discussion of this issue.

Any ideas greatfully received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a fresh crack at the problem this morning, here's what works.

In the UICollectionViewCell

```
class CollectionViewCellA: UICollectionViewCell {

@IBOutlet var image: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var bkgImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var title: UILabel!

var selectTrans: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator?
var scale : CGFloat = 0.0

override func didUpdateFocus(in context: UIFocusUpdateContext, with coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {

    struct wrapper {
        static let s_atvMotionEffect = UIAppleTVMotionEffectGroup()
    }

    coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations( {
        if self.isFocused {
            self.addMotionEffect(wrapper.s_atvMotionEffect)
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.75;
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0;
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 5);
            self.scale = 1.2
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.scale, y: self.scale)
            self.layer.setAffineTransform(transform)
        } else {
            self.removeMotionEffect(wrapper.s_atvMotionEffect)
            self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.25;
            self.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0;
            self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0);
            self.scale = 1.0
            let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: self.scale, y: self.scale)
            self.layer.setAffineTransform(transform)
        }
    },completion: nil)

}

func startSelectAnimation() {
    scale = 1.1
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
    self.layer.setAffineTransform(transform)
    perform(#selector(middleAnimation), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.08)
}

func middleAnimation() {
    scale = 0.95
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
    self.layer.setAffineTransform(transform)
    perform(#selector(endSelectAnimation), with: nil, afterDelay: 0.1)
}

func endSelectAnimation(){
    scale = 1.2
    let transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: scale, y: scale)
    self.layer.setAffineTransform(transform)
}
}
```

In the ViewController

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

         // We have to provide animation, so get the cell and do call to animation
         let selectedCell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCellA
         selectedCell.startSelectAnimation()
         if collectionView == self.freeContentCV {
         performSegue(withIdentifier: "ShowVideoDetail", sender: self)
     }
    }
```

The animation is a little clunky, but when it triggers a segue the jerkiness is not all that noticeable.